# Split a PlasticSCM repository into multiple repositories

Tags: version-control, repository, plasticscm

Our `default` Plastic repository has grown pretty large. It is now bloated with a lot of files that are unrelated, and thus do not need to be versioned together. In hindsight the `default` repository should have been created as several separate repositories.

I'd like to break the `default` repository up into smaller chunks, but I don't want to lose all of the file history by moving files to empty new repositories. What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it choosing any of the following approaches depending on your needs:

- Replicate the original repository as many times as repositories you want to split. Then, delete for each replicated repository the content you will not maintain on it. Doing that you'll preserve the file history, but the database size will not decrease.
- Of course you can create new repositories and add the desired content to the new repositories. This will be a completely new repository, so the DB size will be much smaller.

You will need to decide between big databases preserving the history or fresh databases without file history.